# Yii2: Group by after Order By

Tags: yii2

[I have database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQZxw.png)
pls help me.
I want get listViewCount of Content of subscriber as below

> SELECT 
>       id,
>       subscriber_id,
>       content_id,
>       started_at,
>       stopped_at,
>       view_date FROM
>       (SELECT 
>           *
>       FROM
>           content_view_log
>       WHERE
>           subscriber_id = 19
>       ORDER BY view_date DESC) t GROUP BY content_id;

[lstViewCount when use sql above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RobQD.png)
Pls fix my sql with yii2:

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = ContentViewLog::find();
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'subscriber_id' => $this->subscriber_id,
            'type' => $this->type,
            'site_id' => $this->site_id,
        ]);


        $query->groupBy("content_id");
        $query->orderBy("id desc");

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Comment: `$query = ContentViewLog::find();
 $query->groupBy("content_id");
 $query->orderBy("id desc");
 $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
`

Comment: Sr code the same sampleCode is above. it's not what I want